# Can't set up DataSource for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I am trying to implement DataSource in my Spring Boot (2.3.5.RELEASE with Spring Cloud Hoxton.RELEASE) project.

I have to programmatically set the DataSource's url, username, and password, depending on the environment the app is running in. Also, the values must be loaded from a KV store first.

However, the DataSource is not being set by the `@Bean`. I get this error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

If I change the name of the Bean method to `dataSource`, then I get an error that a Bean with that name already exists.

For the password, an AWS IAM token needs to be generated, so I can't just put the password in the application.properties file.

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialectDialect
```

My Config file:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@DependsOn("appConfiguration")
public class MyDBConfig extends HikariConfig {

    @Value("${db.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${db.name}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Value("${db.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
        
        try {
            DataSourceBuilder<HikariDataSource> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class);

            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + databaseName);
            dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
            dataSourceBuilder.password(AwsRdsTokenGenerator.getIAMAuthToken());

            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to set up DataSource: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I printed above. If I rename the method to just `dataSource` then I get the other error (already exists).

How do I set up my DataSource after I pull the values I need?

Thanks for the help!